# Laravel Livewire: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'code')

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Why am I getting this error when $client is object is clearly not null..?

Blade

```
<div class="max-w-md mx-auto">
        <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-4 pt-6 pb-4 mb-4">
        {{json_encode($client)}}
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="code" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Code:</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="client.code" id="code" class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @unless($editMode) readonly @endunless>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="name" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="client.name" id="name" class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @unless($editMode) readonly @endunless>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-6">
            <label for="office_address" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Office Address:</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="client.office_address" id="office_address" class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @unless($editMode) readonly @endunless>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
            <x-solid-button type="button" background="text-gray-900 bg-white border border-yellow-300 hover:bg-yellow-100 w-20" action="livewire" link="toggleEditMode"
                            component="">
                {{ $editMode ? 'Save' : 'Edit' }}
            </x-solid-button>
            @if ($editMode)
                <button wire:click="cancelEdit" class="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                    Cancel
                </button>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Livewire Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Clients;

use Livewire\Component;

class Details extends Component
{
    public object $client;
    public bool $editMode = false;

    public function mount($client)
    {
        $this->client = (object) $client;
    }

    public function toggleEditMode()
    {
        $this->editMode = !$this->editMode;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.clients.details');
    }

    public function cancelEdit()
    {
        $this->editMode = false;
    }
}
```

I am getting the client data on the page when I use json_encode($client) to view it. But why am I still getting the error..

I couldn't find any solid solution on the internet..what am I missing?

I am using livewire version 3.0

[Check The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfq38.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is $client has been declared but not initialised.

The first option is to update your mount to something like this:

```
 public function mount($client = null)
    {
        
        $clientArray = is_array($client) ? $client : [];
        $defaultClient = [
            'items' => $clientArray['name'] ?? '', 
            'code' => $clientArray['code'] ?? '', 
            'office_address' => $clientArray['office_address'] ?? '', 
        ];

        $this->client = (object) $defaultClient;
    }
```

Or declare each  element separately:

In your Livewire Component:

```
...
public object $code;
public object $name;
public object $office_address;
...
```

In your Blade View:

```
...
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="code" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Code:</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="code" id="code" class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @unless($editMode) readonly @endunless>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="name" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="name" id="name" class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @unless($editMode) readonly @endunless>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-6">
            <label for="office_address" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Office Address:</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="office_address" id="office_address" class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @unless($editMode) readonly @endunless>
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties), `object` is not directly supported as property. You're also using `wire:model` to directly bind to it. Have you tried storing it as `array` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had use to Form Object of livewire..it worked then..

Created a form class using

`php artisan livewire:form ClientForm`

Which creates a client form class in Livewire->Forms directory...

I added the validation rules and update function

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Forms;

use App\Models\Clients;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Livewire\Form;

class ClientForm extends Form
{
    public ?clients $client;

    public $code = '';
    public $name = '';
    public $office_address = '';

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'code' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('clients','code')->ignore($this->client),
            ],
            'name' => 'required',
            'office_address' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function setPost(Clients $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->code = $client->code;
        $this->name = $client->name;
        $this->office_address = $client->office_address;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate();

        Clients::create($this->only(['code', 'name', 'office_address']));
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $this->client->update(
            $this->all()
        );

    }
}
```

This is my updated livewire component, where I called the ClientForm class and update function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Clients;

use App\Livewire\Forms\ClientForm;
use App\Models\Clients;
use Livewire\Component;

class Details extends Component
{
    public ClientForm $form;

    public object $client;
    public bool $isEditing = false;

    public function mount(Clients $client)
    {
        $this->form->setPost($client);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->form->update();
        $this->isEditing = false; // Switch back to read-only mode
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.clients.details');
    }

}
```

Updated blade file:

```
<div class="max-w-md mx-auto">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
        @csrf
        <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-4 pt-6 pb-4 mb-4">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="code" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Code:</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="form.code"
                       class="w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-gray-700 {{$isEditing ? 'bg-white' :'bg-gray-200'}}"
                       @unless($isEditing) disabled @endunless
                >
                @error('form.code')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="name" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="form.name" id="name"
                       class="w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-gray-700 {{$isEditing ? 'bg-white' :'bg-gray-200'}}"
                       @unless($isEditing) disabled @endunless
                >
                @error('form.name')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="office_address" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Office Address:</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="form.office_address" id="office_address"
                       class="w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-gray-700 {{$isEditing ? 'bg-white' :'bg-gray-200'}}"
                       @unless($isEditing) disabled @endunless
                >
                @error('form.office_address')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center justify-around">
                @if ($isEditing)
                    <x-solid-button type="submit"
                                    background="text-gray-900 bg-white border {{$isEditing ?  'border-green-300 hover:bg-green-100' : 'border-yellow-300 hover:bg-yellow-100'}}   w-20"
                                    action="" link=""
                                    component="">
                        Save
                    </x-solid-button>
                    <x-solid-button type="button" background="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700 text-white w-20"
                                    action="livewire" link="$toggle('isEditing')"
                                    component="">
                        Cancel
                    </x-solid-button>
                @else
                    <x-solid-button type="button"
                                    background="text-gray-900 bg-white border border-yellow-300 hover:bg-yellow-100 w-20"
                                    action="livewire" link="$toggle('isEditing')"
                                    component="">
                         Edit
                    </x-solid-button>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```